# How Mojolicious `under` works?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

From [documentation](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Under):

> All following routes are only evaluated if the callback returned a true value.

What does `following` mean?

1. Group of routes that are **only** under this one
2. Routes which are declared later in the code, after this `under`

Also I do not understand what is coming on in next scenario:

```
perl -Mojo -E '
  app->routes->under("/", sub{ warn "R1"; return undef })->get("/r1" => {text => "r1" }); 
  app->routes->under("/", sub{ warn "R2"; return undef })->get("/r2" => {text => "r2" }); 
  app->start;
' 
get /r2
```

Here nothing was matched, so should I got `404` just like at next application:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'app->start;' get /r2
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Your first example only warns (correctly) for both routes, but doesn't return the lower case content. That's because the callbacks need to return a true value. Get rid of the `return undef` and do `1` instead to see both warning and text.

Comment: @simbabque: at first example command never return (this is a problem). I return `undef` because they are restricted to auth users only. Like [at an example](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Tutorial#Under)

Comment: @simbabque:  So both routes are restricted, nothing was matched. Should I get 404 or some error?

Comment: You shoud probably redirect to a login page.

Comment: Or render some message, - anyway returning undef will not render anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption *Here nothing was matched* is not correct. You have a route for `/r2`. The callbacks associated with that route form a chain where each callback might render a response or pass responsibility to the next callback in the chain by returning true.

If you run that code from an application with logging enabled  (logfile `log/development.log` by default) you will see

`[timestamp] [6389] [debug] [Ere90x2U] Nothing has been rendered, expecting delayed response`

indicating that your callbacks returned without rendering anything.

Typically your `under` callback would be used to factor out some common behaviour like checking for access privileges (see the [tutorial](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Growing) ).

In this example the callback redirects to a login page if necessary or returns true to pass control to the next callback in the chain:

```
  my $logged_in = $r->under(sub ($c) {
    return 1 if $c->session('user');
    $c->redirect_to('index');
    return undef;
  });
  $logged_in->get('/protected');
```

Actually, here the callback for `/protected` is implicit and the corresponding template `protected.html.ep` will be rendered.

Comment: This is helpful. But for oneline app the log is not created and debug message is not displayed

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @EugenKonkov what's the use case for one line apps? Surely if you want more sophisticated behaviour like factoring out behaviour like that, you'd invest more than a very long single line.

Comment: @simbabque: they are for learning how `under` works